# Ansible recalculates dictionary values every time a key is accessed

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have a group_vars.yml with dictionary VAULT

```yaml
VAULT:
  SOME_VAR: "{{ lookup('cached','community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault', 'secret=path_to_variable:secret' <auth_info>) }}"
  SOME_VAR_2: "<like some var but another path & secret>
  ...(about 100 other vars)
```

I have several playbooks with same reference to VAULT, they have the following

```yaml
vars:
  docker_env:
    SOME_VAR: "{{VAULT.SOME_VAR}}"
    SOME_VAAAAR: "{{VAULT.SOME_VAR2}}"
    ...(about 50 vars in above style, almost always it is referring to VAULT)
roles:
  - my_role_for_my_containers
    action_type: deploy
```

Role generates docker-compose.yml with list of variables's names (instead of dictionary)

And the problem that generating docker-compose.yml and validating variables in role are **very slow**.
Using plugin *cached* for lookups I got about 4x more speed and realized that each variable from **VAULT** is accessed more than 20 times per playbook, even if they aren't in *docker_env*.

How did I get it?
I found in logs with `-vvv` a lot of rows like for every variable from VAULT during executing playbook

```
'cached' lookup cache hit for ('community.hashi_vault.hashi_vault', ['secret=path_to_variable:secret <auth_info>'], {})
```

I can solve it using `docker_env` without VAULT, like

```yaml
docker_env:
  SOME_VAR: "{{ lookup('cached', 'community.hashi_vault...."
  ...
```

but it's inconvenient way for me, because I separate prod/dev/stage group_vars files and variables for each environment may differ.

So, the question is how can I make ansible work faster with dictionaries with lookups in a better way?

Comment: We'd decided to make all variables independent of the dictionary and added VAULT_ prefix. Like 
VAULT_SOMEVAR:
VAULT_SOMEVAR2:
instead of
VAULT: 
  SOMEVAR:
  SOMEVAR2:...
It boosted playbooks to acceptable time of executing. 
But it's still interesting, why was it so slow